# Remove entry from Windows 7 bootloader

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

After making an error installing windows, I now have two entries in the Windows 7 boot loader, one of which is incorrect.

How can I remove it? I've seen some entries recommending EasyBCD, but can't it be done easily without 3rd party software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to remove an entry in the Windows 7 Boot Configuration is to use msconfig.

To launch msconfig:

1. Click Start
2. In the Search text box, type msconfig
3. Launch msconfig by selecting it from the search results above the search text box.

After msconfig is launched:

1. Go to the Boot tab
2. Slect the boot entry you want to delete.
3. Click the Delete button and then click OK.

[source](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/a8ece38a-2de8-4931-9068-d86aeb4e4da4)

Comment: Thanks! Pretty sure that's exactly what I was looking for. I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 as well.