# Uninstalling windows 8 without formatting the partition

Tags: windows-8, uninstall

I have three partitions:

- `c:\` with XP
- `E:\` data files
- `D:\` with Windows 8 installed.

All is now full of data so won't make space. Due to low resource I want to uninstall Windows 8 . Is there any way to clean uninstall Windows 8 from `D:\` partition (In which windows 8 installed) without formatting it.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/494948/removing-old-windows-from-disk) , with the [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/210969/remove-entry-from-windows-7-bootloader)

Comment: @Goran_Mandic your link to answer in not to uninstall windows8 it only for removing entry from bootloader.

Comment: Once you remove windows 8 from the bootloader, you can erase the folder which it is in.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really an *uninstall* for operating systems. You can just delete the Windows and Program Files directories if you need the space but have no need anymore for Windows. You would still have the Windows 8 boot loader, though but you can probably remove the entry for Windows 8 with `bcdedit` (and make XP the default) so you don't really notice it.