# How do I remove a Windows 7 boot option?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

After getting a new SSD I went on and got windows 7 on that one instead of the HDD.

Now during boot up windows asks me to choose between two copies of Windows 7, where one does not work and the other is fully workable. It didn't bother me much except for the fact that I can't leave my computer while it's booting because it will choose the wrong Windows 7.

My question is how do I remove the faulty one? It's quite annoying to wait for this screen to popup before I can leave it alone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove entry from Windows 7 bootloader](http://superuser.com/questions/210969/remove-entry-from-windows-7-bootloader), [How to remove an old OS from the boot menu](http://superuser.com/questions/465047/how-to-remove-an-old-os-from-the-boot-menu)

Comment: The first link does not work, I only see one entry of Windows 7. The second link is nearly the same problem, I tried the solution posted there but I only see windows boot manager and windows boot loader in bcdedit. 

As for the rest posted in that thread I don't have the knowledge to actually do it on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default operating system by

1. Control Panel
2. System
3. Advanced System Settings
4. Startup and Recovery
5. Default operating system

Select the other Windows 7 from the list and apply the changes. Note that this will not remove the two entries.

To delete an entry, use [`BCDEDIT /remove`](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: There is only one windows 7 under default operating system, which is the one I use. I've tried quite a lot to remove the other one, but I can't even find it on any programs such as easybcd or anything.

PS: I want to remove the "corrupt/faulty" windows 7.

Comment: It would help if you include such facts in your question already. Then we know that you're not just an average user who doesn't find the option.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it might be useful to boot from a Windows 7 install disk and go into the repair mode (instead of installing).

Try the option to repair startup files first.
If that doesn't help you can try manual repair which gives you a command prompt Window.
Here you can try `FIXMBR` to reset the boot-sector and `FIXBOOT` to rewrite the bootloader.
(Run each command with `/?` behind it to see what options, if any, they take.)

Also: Please check that your BIOS actually **BOOTS** from the SSD. If it tries to boot the HDD first that can confuse programs that update the bootloader-entries (like Windows itself or EasyBCD).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however System recovery options gave me this error message: This version is not compatible with the version you are trying to repair." . Manual repair couldn't find the solution.

I've set bios to always pick ssd infront of anything else.

FIMBR and FIXBOOT was not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Thats odd... Are you sure the Win7 install DVD you used was the same as you used to install the Win7 on the SSD in the first place? And that it was in fact a real Windows 7 media. Not some heavily modified "hacker" image with all sorts of stuff "pre-installed"?

Comment: Hi, infact I got the DVD off a friend in which case I got the message "This copy of Windows is not genuine" a couple of days ago, even though I've had it for about 2 years now.

Answer (score 0):

Use MsConfig to clean up the bootfile.

Start > Run > MsConfig > Boot

Comment: Nothing there but the real Windows 7.